# How to send a constant parameter to a camel-stored-procedure execution?

Tags: stored-procedures, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I'm trying to invoke a stored procedure using the [SQL Stored Procedure Camel Component](http://camel.apache.org/sql-stored-procedure.html), but I can't figured out how to send a constant as a parameter (for example an integer). For example:

```
...
<to id="storedSP_E139_T358_UPDATE" uri="sql-stored:SP_E139_T358_UPDATE(INTEGER 1)?dataSource=someDatasource"/>
...
```

Using a simple number, I got:

```
Caused by:     org.apache.camel.component.sql.stored.template.generated.ParseException: Encountered " <IDENTIFIER> "\'1\' "" at line 1, column 29.
Was expecting one of:
    <SIMPLE_EXP_TOKEN> ...
    <PARAMETER_POS_TOKEN> ...
```

Enclosing the number between braces: `${1}`, I got:

```
org.apache.camel.language.simple.types.SimpleIllegalSyntaxException: Unknown function: 1 at location 0
```

I don't want to use  because I don't want to save it to a header before using it, I need to send several constants parameters.

Comment: Why don't you want to save parameters in headers? It's the expected way to do it. You can remove headers after executing the stored procedure.

Comment: There are a lot of parameters and a lot of stored procedures I have to execute, wouldn't be easier just to send them as a simple constant in the uri of the component? ... I guess if there is no alternative, I'll have to do it that way, but I'm surprised that you can not send constants as parameters.

Comment: If they **really** are constant, why don't you define them in the procedure body?

Comment: Anyway you can define a bean to easily process a Camel exchange body into appropriate headers.

Comment: The SPs are called from other places with different values for those parameters, they can't be hard-coded in the procedure body. I've used several <setHeader/> tags to set those parameters, but I think that it would be a cool new feature to accept constants in the SP call. Thanks anyway!